# Magento2 Invoice and delivery the same checked by default

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I can't figure out how to check the "Invoice and delivery address are the same" checkbox by default. Is this a setting that I'm missing or is this something which should be handled from within a theme?

If so the easiest way is with Javascript and add a JS file and see if the address is empty when entering the page. But with a server value it is more accurate, is this something which then should be handled in the LayoutProcessor? Or what is the best way to approach this.